# Comparing cells to see if one is blank and then counting the total of blank cells

Tags: excel

I have a data set where I am wanting to compare two column figures to check if one column is blank.

For instance, say this is my data.

A | B

5 |

3 | 8

| 5

6 |

If column B is blank I want to write "Loss" in column C, for each "loss" row. Then when this is applied, how would I do a sum of the losses? Will excel count a string?

Comment: Use COUNTIF() to count and a simple IF statement to fill column C

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, I am really new to Excel, at least with formulas. I tried doing this `=IF(B2<>"Loss")`, but it just throws errors. The thing is, some cells will be losses and some will be gains..such as A4 shown in this example, Is there anyway to formulate both options in one formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Scott suggests... use a simple `IF()` statement, then use a simple `COUNTIF()` function.

[image: simple if and countif]

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to check for gains simultaneously, such as your row 6?

Comment: Well, I mean to combine the formulas, in order to to check both columns A and B for growth or losses. So it would pick row 6 as a gain and row 4 as a loss, etc.

Comment: Nested IF() statement - IF(IF()).  You can do it, think it through. :)

Comment: I feel bad... here you go `=IF(B7="","Loss",IF(A7="","Gain",""))`

Comment: I was actually close! I was posting this. `=IF(ORIF(F4="","Loss",""),E4="","Gain","")`

Comment: Well, not too close, but I am not familiar with the formula formats yet.

Comment: That result was perfect. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I am attempting to work a similar thing with the same problem, except I am trying to get the sum of all the rows with "Gain". The result is giving me an blank value. I believe it is because of my nested if part, but I am trying to check for when it is blank to not count the F value... Do I need to add the "Loss" in it as well? `=IF(H4:H185="Gain", SUM(F4:F185),IF(H4:H185="",""))`

Comment: Look at how the `SUMIF()` function works.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b